# R gsub on a large string, many patterns, one replacement

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub

I have:
- x: a list of 500.000 strings of around 200 characters each
- lastname: a list of 40.000 common last names

I need to replace all last names in all string by the code word "LASTNAME".  This takes a lot of time (hours) and I would like to speed it up.

My first attempt was superslow, as it looped through the list of strings 40.000 times:

```
for (i in 1:length(lastname)){
        x <- gsub(x, pattern = paste0("\\b", lastname[i], "\\b", sep = ""), replacement = "LASTNAME")
}
```

I then decided to group the last names in regex groups of 100, seperated by "|", e.g. "\bArnolds\b|\bBeckham\b|\bCollins\b|...".  I tested different values, but 100 seemed the best performing.  The code now only loop 40.000/100 = 400 times through the string list.

```
# Function to make the grouped pattern
groupPat <- function(pat0, ng)
{
    # pat0: original list of patterns
    # ng: number of original patterns in one group
    # pat1: new, grouped pattern

    # Length of original pattern
    np0 <- length(pat0)

    # Length of pattern to make
    np1 <- floor(np0/ng)

    if (np1 > 0){
        # Allocate memory
        pat1 <- vector(mode = "list", length = np1)

        # Make new pattern
        for (i in 1:np1-1){
            pat1[i] <- paste0("\\b", pat0[(i*ng+1):((i+1)*ng)], "\\b", collapse = "|")
        }
        pat1[np1] <- paste0("\\b", pat0[(np1*ng+1):np0], "\\b", collapse = "|") 
    } else {
        pat1 <- paste0("\\b", pat0, "\\b", collapse = "|")
    }

    # Output
    pat1    
}


# The actual replacement loop:
pat <- groupPat(lastname, 100)
for (i in 1:length(pat)){
    x <- gsub(x, pattern = pat[i], replacement = "LASTNAME")
}
```

Is there a way to speed this up more?

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: It looks to me that a more reasonable grouping of last names may help. Like, for example, try to split them in a way that in each group all last names have similar first two letters. Then you'll be a able to construct a more efficient regex. E.g. if a group consists of `"Jones"` and `"Johnson"`, the regex would be `"\\bJo[nes|hnson]\\b"`.

Comment: You could experiment with running this in `parallel` with `parSapply`.  That may yield some benefit if the regular expression has a long enough execution time.

Comment: Thanks for the info so far.
For akrun:

Comment: For akrun, I put a reproducable code here:
https://justpaste.it/12m38